# FX TextField Disabled Node Events

Tags: java, css, swing, javafx

I am well aware of the Java FX Node API which states:

> A disabled Node does not receive mouse or key events.

So, I am trying to come up with a work around.  In our old Swing application we used to allow users to double click on a disabled web/email field (Formatted TextField) to open a link to the page or their native mail client.  I am hoping to simulate this behavior in FX.  Instead of calling:

```
setDisable(true);
```

I am now calling:

```
setEditable(false);
```

The only remaining issue is that I would like to style the Node as if it were disabled, or at minimum disable text selection.

Is there a simple way to get the exact style of the Node when it is disabled, or will I need to create my own CSS class? (Unfortunately my CSS knowledge is relatively weak).

Answer (score 3):

I can't see an "easy" way to do this with CSS, without replicating the default rules for a disabled text field (but maybe someone else has a trick for that).

Here's a completely different approach, though. When the text field is disabled, it doesn't receive mouse events, so any mouse events will just "drop through" to the node below it in Z-order. So if you wrap the text field in some pane, and register a mouse handler with the pane, that mouse handler will get invoked if the text field is disabled.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DIsabledTextFieldEventTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        StackPane textFieldHolder = new StackPane(textField);

        CheckBox disableTextField = new CheckBox("Disable text field");
        textField.disableProperty().bind(disableTextField.selectedProperty());

        textFieldHolder.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                System.out.println("Double click on disabled text field!");
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, disableTextField, textFieldHolder);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This was definitely a thought of ours, however these are custom components that are used on multiple screens.  I guess they could just extend StackPane instead of TextField and when setting/getting the value we could just do pane.getTextField().getValue() instead.  This might end up being the preferred solution.

Comment: Your custom component could also just expose the textField's `textProperty()` (and other properties as needed); i.e. `public StringProperty textProperty() { return textField.textProperty(); }`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way to get the exact style of the Node when it is disabled, or will I need to create my own CSS class?

If you do the below to your non-editable text field, it looks exactly like a disabled text field (tested on my MacBook).

`textField.setStyle("-fx-opacity:0.5");`